Getting Validation Failed: Path is required Error even when I am providing all the required data
I am using Mongoose in my Nodejs application and I want to create a new Experience collection. For that I am providing all the data in Postman. I am using application/x-www-form-urlencoded to send my data. But I keep Getting the error
"Experience validation failed: experience.from: Path experience.from is required., experience.company: Path experience.company is required., experience.title: Path experience.title is required."
again and again. I have checked my Schema and my code for any spell mistakes but I don't seem to find any. I have checked this error on many sites but the answer always seems to be either spell mistakes or "requires should be set to false in Schema". But I have put required to true because I need that.
Here is my Schema
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const experienceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    experience: {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        location: String,
        from: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
        },
        to: {
            type: Date,
        },
        current: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        description: String,
    },
});

const Experience = mongoose.model("Experience", experienceSchema);

export default Experience;


Here is my Route file for Experience
import express from "express";
import Profile from "../models/Profile.js";
import Experience from "../models/Experience.js";
import auth from "../middleware/auth.js";
import { body, validationResult } from "express-validator";

const router = express.Router();

// Create Experience
// Endpoint experience/
router.post(
    "/",
    auth,
    body("title", "Please provide your title").notEmpty().trim(),
    body("company", "Please provide your company name").notEmpty().trim(),
    body("location").trim(),
    body("from", "From date is required").notEmpty().trim(),
    body("to").trim(),
    body("current").isBoolean(),
    body("description").trim(),
    async (req, res) => {
        let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.userid });
        if (!profile) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .send("Profile does not exist! Please create a Profile.");
        }

        const result = validationResult(req);

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: result.array() });
        }

        const { title, company, location, from, to, current, description } =
            req.body;

        try {
            const experienceFields = new Experience({
                title,
                company,
                location,
                from,
                to,
                current,
                description,
            });

            await experienceFields.save();

            return res.json(experienceFields);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send("Server Error...");
        }
    }
);

Here's my index.js file
import express from "express";
import connectDB from "./db.js";
import user from "./routes/user.js";
import auth from "./routes/auth.js";
import profile from "./routes/profile.js";
import experience from "./routes/experience.js";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/user", user);
app.use("/auth", auth);
app.use("/profile", profile);
app.use("/experience", experience);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

connectDB();


Here is an image of my data in Postman
enter image description here
I tried sending data as raw json and using json() parser as middleware but it keeps giving the same error.

Your schema has the wrong structure. The experience model has one field experience structured as an object with fields user, title, etc., so your experience object looks like this:
{
    "experience": {
        "user": {...},
        "title": "example title",
        "company": "example company"
        ...
    }
}

instead of:
{
    "user": {...},
    "title": "example title",
    "company": "example company"
    ...
}

You should "flatten" the schema to remove the wrapping experience object:
const experienceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    location: String,
    from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    },
    to: {
        type: Date,
    },
    current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    description: String,
});

const Experience = mongoose.model("Experience", experienceSchema);

export default Experience;

